# How to select the correct submit button with mechanize for Python?

Tags: mechanize-python

I'm trying to submit a form (using mechanize in Python) that has two submit buttons as shown below.

```
<input type="submit" value="Save Changes " name="SaveChanges">
<input type="submit" value="Reboot" name="SaveChanges">
```

Mechanize "print control" shows this...

```
<SubmitControl(SaveChanges=Save Changes )>
<SubmitControl(SaveChanges=Reboot)>
```

How do I select the "Reboot" submit button with mechanize?  I've tried:

```
br.submit()
br.submit("Reboot")
br.submit("SaveChanges=Reboot")
```

The correct form is selected, but none of these submit options are working.  I'm new to Python and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured it out.

```
br.submit(nr=1)
```

will select the second submit button (nr count starts with zero)